# Get text between 2 parentheses, including nested parentheses

Tags: php

I want to get in between () in a text like this and put them in an array but there may be some nested parentheses inside.

Text:

```
(This (is) a example) (on what i want)
```

It should be processed like this:

```
$array["this (is) a example"] = "on what i want";
```

how can i do this?

Comment: I edited the question assuming you meant "parenthesis" instead of "comma".  I left your invalid `array` syntax alone, however.  If what you want is an array of strings, that'd be `array("this (is) an example", "of what I want")`.

Comment: @MarkReed Maybe the OP meant: `$array["this (is) an example"] = "of what I want";`

Comment: @PhpMyCoder right, I didn't want to assume, which is why I didn't edit that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = '(This (is) a example) (on what i want)';

unset($matches);
preg_match_all('/^\\((.*)\\)[ \\t]+\\((.*)\\)$/', $s, $matches);
$array[$matches[1][0]] = $matches[2][0];

var_dump($array);
```

This is possible because the `.*` is *greedy* and tries to match the longest string between parentheses while still making sure that the whole pattern will match.

Comment: this wont work for me shouldnt the `preg_match_all('/^\((.*)\) \((.*)\)$/', $s, $matches);` be in some sort of variable and what is $matches ?

Comment: `preg_match_all` puts all of it's matches into $matches, which is passed by reference. What exactly "won't work"?

Comment: the code, it won't put the stuff in the array, and yes i am using $this->array in a class.

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($s);` and `var_dump($this->array);`.

Comment: That is because in your real data there is more than a space between the two blocks. Updated the answer.