# How to get all values in parentheses in a string including nested parentheses?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Desired Behaviour**

I have an input validation that, amongst other things, tests for length (`< 140 chars`).

My input accepts markdown, and I'd like to *exclude* the length of the URLs in my length calculation.

For example, something that appears as:

> here is a very long link to this article on [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

is `57` characters long, whereas the actual code for it is `155` characters long, ie:

```js
here is a very long link to this article on [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
```

The scenarios that need to be covered are things like:

`text and [a markdown link](https://google.com)`

`text (and [a markdown link within parenthesis](https://google.com))`

This question is about:

How to get all values in parentheses in a string including nested parentheses.

**What I've Tried**

My current approach to the overall problem is:

1. get all values within parentheses in the string
2. if any start with `https`, create a copy of the string
3. remove the values from the copied string
4. get the length of the adjusted string and run length validation on that

These are my attempts at the first part:

**01)**

This solution just gets the first "match", source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059321

```js
var text = "here is a (very) long link to this article on [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)";

var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;

var matches = regExp.exec(text);
console.log(matches);
// 0: "(very)"
// 1: "very"
```

**02)**

This solution gets all matches, with the parenthesis' included, source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30674943

```js
var text = "here is a (very) long link to this article on [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)";

var regExp = /(?:\()[^\(\)]*?(?:\))/g;

var matches = text.match(regExp);
console.log(matches);
// 0: "(very)"
// 1: "()"
// 2: "(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)"
```

But it doesn't work as expected in the nested parenthesis scenario, ie:

```js
var text = "text (and [a markdown link within parenthesis](https://google.com))";

var regExp = /(?:\()[^\(\)]*?(?:\))/g;

var matches = text.match(regExp);
console.log(matches);
// ["(https://google.com)"]
```

**03)**

There is a `php` regex solution here that seems to be related:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994041

but i couldn't figure out how to implement that regex in javascript, ie:

```
preg_match_all('/^\\((.*)\\)[ \\t]+\\((.*)\\)$/', $s, $matches);
```

Comment: I would recommend to find a library that renders the markdown, and then you validate against the output. it could make your life easier.

Comment: Hmm, i actually already use [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) for an editor feature, i will look into the docs.

Comment: For reference, it seems the markdown-it `render` and `renderInline` [methods](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/#MarkdownIt.render) render markdown strings into html, so it still wouldn't get the 'pure text'. I also use [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) and looked into their docs but it doesn't seem to be designed for 'converting markdown to text'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression that also requires the part in square brackets to precede the link that's within parentheses.

```
/\[([^\]]+)\]\([^)]+\)/g
```

Make sure to use the `g` flag. This also includes a capture group so you can differentiate the "visible" part (between square brackets) from the rest that is "invisible":

```js
var text = "here is a (very) long link to this article on [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)";

var regExp = /\[([^\]]+)\]\([^)]+\)/g;

var match;
while (match = regExp.exec(text)) {
     console.log("full match: " + match[0]);
     console.log("keep: " + match[1]);
}
```

You can actually use a `replace` call to remove the "invisible" part. That makes it easy to calculate the total number of visible characters:

```js
var text = "here is a (very) long link to this article on [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)";

var regExp = /\[([^\]]+)\]\([^)]+\)/g;

console.log("original length: " + text.length);
console.log("visible length: " + text.replace(regExp, "$1").length);
```

Comment: Just to increase/confirm understanding of first solution, would you mind describing exactly how the `while` loop is working?  ie i can see it means while `something` is true, log the values, and when `something` is false stop.  Does that mean `as long as the regex is returning matches, log values, otherwise stop`.  I was reading this article and I think that's right but just wanted to confirm:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: Indeed, an assignment happens in the `while` condition (some may object to such a side-effect, but it is commonly done with a loop on `RegExp#exec`). Now `exec` always returns an object (an array) or `null`. Only in the latter case will this `while` condition be false, and it happens when there are no more matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(?<=\()[^()]+(?=\))`

Explanation:

`(?<=\()` - assert with positive lookbehind that what preceds is `(`

`[^()]+` - match one or more of any characters other than `(` and `)`

`(?=\))` - assert with positive lookahead that what follows is `)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBIi7S/1)